# Convert MLMultiArray to C#/.Net equivalent? Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, coreml

MLMultiArray below, I need this using simple csharp/.net types so I can use with web service which doesn't use Xamarin IOS types.

Type:
MLMultiArray Final_heatmaps_0 {get; set;}

Usage:

```
MLMultiArray Final_heatmaps_0   {Float32 1 × 1 × 19 × 32 × 32 array}    
base    {Foundation.NSObject}   
ClassHandle 0x1fe40a010 
Shape   {System.nint[5]}    
[0] 1   
[1] 1   
[2] 19  
[3] 32  
[4] 32  
Static members      
Non-public members      
class_ptr   0x1fe40a010 
Non-public members      
_Shape  0x283ab5ec0
```

Heres what I'm trying to do

[image: see image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the information , obviously `Shape` is a `nint` list .

So Directly get the value with `.Shape`.

```
MLMultiArray array = xxx;
nint[] data = array.Shape;
```

You can use `data` in  csharp .

Comment: Thanks @ColeX, I need to access .FloatValue and I can't using nint[].

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < heatmapWidth; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < heatmapHeight; y++)
                        {
                            int index = y + heatmapHeight * (x + heatmapWidth * i);
                            if (heatmaps[index].FloatValue > confidence)
                            {
                                confidence = heatmaps[index].FloatValue;
                                positionX = x;
                                positionY = y;
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: I need to create an identical array to mlmultiarray in order to do the same operation with it, meaning the shape And the values inside need to be the same, I've added images of what I'm trying to do Heatmaps is the MLMultiarray Floats is the Csharp float[]

Comment: I know it , I mean what is the exact problem ? Does the code  build successfully ? Or does the output work as expected ?