# Covert MLMultiArray (swift) to C# (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to convert a MLMultiArray to a C# array so I can achieve the the below

```
//TRYING TO ACHIEVE
heatmaps is a MLMultiArray with a shape of (1,19,19,32,32)
var keypointCount = (int)heatmaps.Shape[2] - 1;
var heatmapWidth = (int)heatmaps.Shape[3];
var heatmapHeight = (int)heatmaps.Shape[4];

for (int i = 0; i < keypointCount; i++)
{
    int positionX = 0;
    int positionY = 0;
    
    float confidence = 0.0f;
    
    for (int x = 0; x < heatmapWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < heatmapHeight; y++)
        {
            int index = y + heatmapHeight * (x + heatmapWidth * i);
            
            if (heatmaps[index].FloatValue > confidence)
            {
                confidence = heatmaps[index].FloatValue;
                
                positionX = x;
                positionY = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//POSSIBLE SOLUTION 
//This code below is something I found using a Float[] instead of MLMultiArray however I need it in C sharp

var a: [Float] = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
var m = try! MLMultiArray(a)

if let b = try? UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(m) {
  let c = Array(b)
  print(c)
}
```

here's what I'm currently trying to do the mlmultiarray has a shape of 5, but has over 10,000 values, how can I mirror this with a float[]? does it have to be float[5] , but then I get a iteration error, so I'm using float[mlmultiarray.count] but this doesn't seem to work either as I think its a 1D array so the results aren't right

[image: ml multiarray]

[image: what I'm trying to do]

Comment: how is this question different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160305/convert-mlmultiarray-to-c-net-equivalent-xamarin-ios?

Comment: @Jason Thanks for response, unfortunately that question didn't resolve issue as seen above the comment on the other question only gives the shape, not the values

Comment: what is the first block of code you posted?  Is it an attempt at a solution?  If so, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Jason I need to call this code in an ASP.Net application, therefore I cannot use the heatmaps array as it is a MLMultiArray, rather I need to find a solution that puts that data into a C sharp type array which is the same Shape and has the same data stored in it

Comment: have you tried just iterating through the array using Item and Count?  This does not seem particularly difficult.

Comment: @Jason yes tried this it doesn't work as the array is multidimensional

Comment: MLMultiArray has methods that allow you to treat it as a single dimensional array,  Or you could convert it to a multidimensional C# array.  You haven't demonstrated that you've tried anything to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for helping, I have been trying to convert it too a C# Multidimensional array but here's where I become unstuck I tried to copy the shape making // var floats = new  float[1,19,19,32,32] ;
var index = [0,0,0,0,0,];
while (floats.Count < heatmaps.Count)
{
   floats[index] = heatmaps[index];
 
   index++;
  //here's where I don't know how to copy as usually for 1d array I could increment but as index is an array I'm unsure how to proceed. 
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't have real `MLMultiArray` data to test with, but something like this should work

```
// length of outer array
var length = heatmap.Shape.Length;

// linear counter
var linear = 0;

for (var outer = 0; outer < length; outer++)
{
  for (var inner = 0; inner < heatmap.Shape[outer]; inner++)
  {
     // this is the element at heatmap[outer,inner]
     var item = heatmap.Item[linear];

     // here add it to C# array
     
     // increment linear counter
     linear++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is so close, unfortunately it returns different results to the mlmultiarray, I think its due to the shape I'm trying to create    var dotnetFloats = new float[heatmaps.Count] (this number is usually around 10,000)    as if I don't use the heatmaps count I get an iteration error as we try to iterate past number of floats in the list, So dotnetFloats shows 10,000 elements inside...but when I hover over HeatMaps it shows only 5 elements inside.

Comment: Not sure whether it will help but I've added images of the Shape of the multi array and the code below